# Get the names of all Triggers currently in the database via SQL statement (Oracle SQL Developer)

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I need a sql statement that retrieves the names of all triggers currently setup in the database.
I am using Oracle SQL Developer version 1.5.5, with java version 1.7.

Something like this:

> select OBJECT_NAME from OBJECTS where OBJECT_TYPE = 'Trigger'

Comment: you have a VERY old SQL Developer.  Get the [latest](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/downloads/index.html), I think 4.0 is already out.  You can easily browse for db objects like triggers

Comment: @tbone this is what we use in oil and gas! haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is pretty close:

```
select owner, object_name
from all_objects
where object_type = 'TRIGGER'
```

Or more usefully:

```
select owner, trigger_name, table_owner, table_name, triggering_event
from all_triggers
```

`all_triggers` has other columns to give you more information that `all_objects` does, like when the trigger fires. You can get more information about this and other useful data dictionary view [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e17110/statviews_2120.htm).

Comment: Yes! that is it.  Thanks sir! Looks like my OWNER and TABLE_OWNER are all the same.